# Poster image click play the video but player play button not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, html5-video, video.js

I have the following code on our site to play HTML5 Video and it plays perfectly in All browsers. this is my html code

```
    <video id="video_1" onclick="this.play();" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="" width="100%" height="100%"
          poster="<?php echo get_field('video_image');?>">
        <source src="<?php echo get_field('video_url_mp4');?>" type='video/mp4'/>
        <source src="<?php echo get_field('video_url_webm');?>" type='video/webm'/>
        <source src="<?php echo get_field('video_url_ogg');?>" type='video/ogg' />
        <source src="<?php echo get_field('video_url_flv');?>" type='video/flv' />
    </video>
```

here is my script code

```
var video = document.getElementById('video_1');video.addEventListener('click',function(){video.play();},false);
```

My trouble is, video player play button not working. When play the video but it play the video only poster image click.
how can i fix this please try to help me..

Answer (score 1):

html:-

```
<div id="video_cotainer">
    <video id="video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls="controls" preload="none" width="100%" height="100%" poster="<?php echo get_field('video_image');?>">
            <source src="<?php echo get_field('video_url_mp4');?>" type='video/mp4'/>
            <source src="<?php echo get_field('video_url_webm');?>" type='video/webm'/>
            <source src="<?php echo get_field('video_url_ogg');?>" type='video/ogg' />
            <source src="<?php echo get_field('video_url_flv');?>" type='video/flv' />
    </video>
</div>
```

script:-

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#video_cotainer').click( function(){
            $('#video_1').get(0).play();
            $('#video_cotainer').unbind('click');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Already you have used video controls,Then why you are using JavaScript,That video tag controls attribute is native for play/pause videos.

[Example](http://jsbin.com/apopEBUb/1/edit)

Karthikeyan Siva